# Middleware doesn't run on pages you've already visited Next.js 13+ (13.4.10)

Tags: redirect, middleware, next.js13

I created a middleware to redirect my user to login if a cookie was not present in the request. I've noticed that sometimes, after deleting the cookie, I don't get redirected. After experimenting it seems that whenever I visit a page that I've already visited (pre-cached?) next.js middleware doesn't run. I have a log that should print whenever the middleware runs but it doesn't print on previously visited pages. Can anyone offer a solution to ensure the middleware runs on every page, even those already visited? I may move this "redirect" logic to the next.config.js but I wanted to use this as middleware more as an example on how middleware works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that since I was using Next Link, using my navbar to navigate, just changed the page based off of what was cached so it entirely bypassed the middleware. I'd like to know if there is a way for Next Link to work with middleware in this way but it doesn't look like it.